# Sinusoidal fitting classes for c#

Tags: c#, curve-fitting

I am wondering if there is a class for fitting data to a sine curve. I found an algorithm for it [here](http://www.s3.kth.se/signal/reports/00/IR-S3-SB-0009.pdf) but it would take some time to first understand and then code... Before I go down that road I am wondering if the forum knows of a class that is already created for such mathematical modeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# does not have a long tradition of scientific computing libraries...

My take would be to get one of the numerous numerical computation routine packages (like on of [them](http://cliodhna.cop.uop.edu/~hetrick/c-sources.html), or the Numerical Recipes) in C/C++, and wrap it under C#.

See also [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36725/how-to-fit-a-curve-to-a-sinusoidal-wave).

On the commercial side, [NMath library](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath/) has a `MultiVariableFunctionFitter` class that is would be perfect for you.

Finally, see [this Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#.NET_Framework_Languages_C.23.2C_F.23_and_VB.NET).