# Is there a c# lib to fit data to normal distribution?

Tags: c#, math, normal-distribution

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504278/are-there-any-libraries-in-c-sharp-that-can-fit-the-data-to-normal-distribution) but it has no exact answer.

What I need is given a real world data set: `List<double>` and assume it fits a normal distribution. I need to get the distribution(the mean and sdv).  I am using [math.net](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) to calculate data in my application. Can math.net do this and how? Or is there any other C# library can do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would you agree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741863/gaussian-fit-in-c-sharp is a dupe?

Comment: Or if you are happy to pay, [NMath appears to be able to do this](http://www.centerspace.net/blog/nmath/nmath-tutorial/distribution-fitting-demo/)

Comment: @AakashM, yes I've searched those questions and none of them gives a simple C# solution, they either wrap C/C++ code with C# or re-implement by their own. It is better if there's an handy library. And, much better if it's free.

Comment: Just to clarify, you need to obtain estimates of the distribution parameters, right?

Comment: it's a link off the math.net home page. Yes it can calculate stdev and means. http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/statistics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters) gives you formulas to calculate the estimates of the normal distribution parameters. The expressions are simple so you actually don't need any third party libraries to perform the calculations.

Comment: Thanks Gebb, seems like I have to calc it myself. I'd thought Math.Net could do this. However, if there's another distribution to be fit I still need to re-calc the parameters, whose formula may not be so simple. Is it true that there's no free C# library to use?

Comment: @ChrisLee: I don't know of any library allowing to estimate arbitrary distribution parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the CenterSpace NMath team.  We use a robust trust region minimizer to solve this nonlinear fitting problem.  Depending on your data you may be able to do this with the more widely accessible [Levenberg-Marquardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) minimization algorithm well documented on wikipedia.

http://www.centerspace.net/distribution-fitting-demo/

No our library isn't free...but this code may give you some ideas.

Best,

Paul